# How to run Nuget update in TFS 2013 script

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'd like to have my TFS 2103 build update some of the NuGet packages in the project to their latest versions before the build.

I've written a pre-build script to do this by invoking the nugget.exe update command:

```
& .\.nuget\nuget update ".\XXX.Main.Web\XXX.Main.Web.csproj" -Source Initial -Safe -Id XXX.Feature.Test -Verbosity detailed
```

The log file contains:

> Looking for installed packages in 'packages'. Updating
>   'XXX.Main.Web'... NuGet.CommandLineException: Unable to find
>   'XXX.Feature.Test'. Make sure they are specified in packages.config.

I've tried running the command manually on the build server from the command prompt and it works as I would expect.  I've also checked that script is being run from the correct folder.

The package certainly exists in Packages.config.

Has anyone managed to get nugget.exe update working successfully within a TFS powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

After much head scratching I've found that the pre-build script is run pre fetching the packages from NuGet.  Running the powershell script manually after the build had completed was fine as the packages has subsequently downloaded.

The NuGet message is somewhat misleading.

My solution is to run a NuGet.exe restore command prior to runing the update command and everything now works.